# Cross Validation with One Class Classification in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data, numpy

I'm trying to do cross-validation with One Class Classification - I'm using the PyOD lib - but I don't know if I'm doing it right. The precision is too low and I'm also not able to bring up the mean and standard deviation of F1

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, f1_score, recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score


k = 10
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None)

acc_score = []
pr_score = []
rc_score = []
model = clf
 
for train_index , test_index in kf.split(X, Y):
    x_train , x_test = X.iloc[train_index,:],X.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train , y_test = Y[train_index] , Y[test_index]
     
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    pred_values = model.predict(x_test)
  
       
    acc = accuracy_score(pred_values , y_test)
    acc_score.append(acc)
    avg_acc_score = sum(acc_score)/k
    pr = precision_score(pred_values, y_test)
    pr_score.append(pr)
    avg_pr_score=sum(pr_score)/k
    rc = recall_score(pred_values, y_test)
    rc_score.append(rc)
    avg_rc_score=sum(rc_score)/k
    
print('accuracy of each fold - {}'.format(acc_score))
print('Avg accuracy : {}'.format(avg_acc_score))
print('Precision: {}'.format(avg_pr_score))
print('Recall: {}'.format(avg_rc_score))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are dividing by 10 (k) at each iteration, I can think to try to calculate the average, this is incorrect and probably it is what is causing you to see a very low metric value. It would be simpler and correct, to only store the values for the metric in each iteration at the validation set and finally just calculate the average and std of the list in which you stored the values.

Try:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, f1_score, recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score


k = 10
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None)

acc_score = []
pr_score = []
rc_score = []
model = clf
 
for train_index , test_index in kf.split(X, Y):
    x_train , x_test = X.iloc[train_index,:],X.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train , y_test = Y[train_index] , Y[test_index]
     
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    pred_values = model.predict(x_test)
  
       
    acc = accuracy_score(pred_values , y_test)
    acc_score.append(acc)
    pr = precision_score(pred_values, y_test)
    pr_score.append(pr)
    rc = recall_score(pred_values, y_test)
    
print(f'accuracy of each fold - {acc_score}')
print(f'Avg accuracy :{np.mean(acc_score)} ± {np.std(acc_score)} std')
print(f'Precision:{np.mean(pr_score)} ± {np.std(pr_score)} std')
print(f'Recall:{np.mean(rc_score)} ± {np.std(rc_score)} std')
```